# Is there a way to have queuing mechanism in files upload other than using activeMQ

Tags: java

We need to implement a queuing based mechanism(picking one file process it and pick the next file). Is there is any other mechanisms other than ActiveMQ mechansim to implement this requirement?

Answer (score 5):

There are many possible ways to achieve what you are looking for. Some of most used MQ are given below .
IBM MQ:-

IBM WebSphere MQ handles the different processors, operating systems, subsystems, and communication protocols it encounters in transferring the message. If a connection or a processor is temporarily unavailable, IBM WebSphere MQ queues the message and forwards it when the connection is back online. 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q001020_.htm

Kafka:-
it is written in Java and it is now under the Apache project umbrella. Kafka is the architecture, it stores the messages in flat files and consumers ask messages based on an offset
https://dzone.com/articles/exploring-message-brokers

Apache Apollo:-
Apache ActiveMQ Apollo gets competition from its own company. Apollo is a recent development based on the experience of the ActiveMQ project.

In order to be faster, more robust and easier to maintain than ActiveMQ, a completely new architecture was introduced. That architecture is based on Scala programming language, which supports well the development of concurrent systems. The threading of the Apollo broker differs fundamentally from that of the ActiveMQ. All tasks are performed asynchronously and non-blocking which contributes to increased performance and stability. This means that the skills of multi-core processors are better used."Although Apollo is written in Scala, the broker can be used safely in a Java environment"

FFMQ:-
The Full-Java, native JMS, message Queuer is a lightweight JMS implementation. The whole server is smaller than 600 KB but there are a number of restrictions regarding JMS conformity or transactions. If you can dispense with advanced JMS functionality such as Message Groups gets a simple, fast and straightforward message broker with FFMQ.
Apache Qpid:-
Besides ActiveMQ and Apollo there is another Apache Message Broker, Apache Qpid. The aim of the Qpid project is the 100 percent compatibility with the Advanced Message Queuing Protocol Standard.

Qpid broker is available for C++ and Java. This article describes the features of the Java version. For Java clients there is a JMS API for Qpid. For C++, Python and Microsoft's .NET there is the Qpid Messaging API.

RabbitMQ:-
The RabbitMQ broker was created by the functional language Erlang. Erlang is especially suited for distributed applications, as concurrency and availability is well-supported.

Do not be deterred from that RabbitMQ is implemented in Erlang. Its installation runs quickly and easily at Windows and Mac OS. For programming in Java or other languages client libraries are available.

The ActiveMQ broker has limitations in terms of scalability, robustness and reliability due to its architecture. But only at extremely high load or at thousands of queues ActiveMQ should show its limits. In practice, ActiveMQ often is more stable than its modern challenger because of its maturity.

Comment: Hi Ann, thnks for the detailed reply. But myself was not looking for any third party APIs as you have mentioned. Mentioned are third party apis just like Active MQ right?

Comment: Vishnu so u should have mentioned in question itself and question seems to added without proper research or of lesser idea i hope u have visited stacked over flow help center to how to post question

Comment: nervgh/angular-file-upload is one of the popular file upload queuing mechanism. https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Introduction.